# Push notification service that allows multiple certificates

Tags: swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I always used Parse for my applications and I cannot seem to find a service anywhere that allows for multiple apps to utilize one backend (multiple .p12s uploaded to utilize push app to app). Does Firebase, Kinvey, or any service not allow this yet?

Answer (score 0):

push notification certificate create by Bundle ID,the bundle ID is unique about the app.so the push notification certificate can't allow multiple certificates.